# pre-commit - validate json-like files

Tags: json, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

in our project we add a big number of `json-like files`, which have a json structure, but are named with `.meta` extension (not a `.json`). We would like to **validate the files against the `json-schema`** before pushing them to the repo.

We already use the pre-commit tool and I have found the check-jsonschema hook for pre-commit: https://github.com/python-jsonschema/check-jsonschema. I have already tested the plugin, but **it only works for the files that are ended with the `.json` extensions, not the ‘.meta’ ones**, even if I pass the proper regexp via the `files` parameter. So:

`^data/.*\.json` -> `data/file1.json` works (found a schema violation)
`^data/.*\.meta` -> `data/file1.meta` does not works (skips validating file)

**Any workaround to make file names with `.meta` extension be validated?**
**Any suggestion of other pre-commit plugin?**

---

Pre-commit configuration:

```
# .pre-commit-config.yaml
repos:
- repo: https://github.com/python-jsonschema/check-jsonschema
  rev: '0.27.3'
  hooks:
    - id: check-jsonschema
      name: Validate meta files
      args: ["--schemafile", "schemas/my_schema.json"]
      files: ^data/.*\.meta$
```

Schema file:

```
# schemas/my_schema.json
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "my-key": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "my-key"
    ]
}
```

Example data:

```
# data/file1.meta
# data/file1.json
{
    “another-key”: “value”
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that hook uses [types](https://pre-commit.com/#filtering-files-with-types) by [default](https://github.com/python-jsonschema/check-jsonschema/blob/0172560f9f44770ba89936999979d9d2aaf46f05/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml#L6) to classify files

since your `.meta` files are not going to be classified as either `yaml` or `json` you need to either (1) rename them so they are (by adding `.json` to the filenames) or (2) override the filtering to manually work via filename instead

I would recommend adding a special hook and keeping the original one in place.  using your example it would look something like this:

```yaml
repos:
- repo: https://github.com/python-jsonschema/check-jsonschema
  rev: '0.27.3'
  hooks:
    - id: check-jsonschema
      # not necessary, but can be useful for `pre-commit run` if you have other `check-jsonschema` hooks
      alias: check-jsonschema-meta  
      name: Validate meta files
      args: ["--schemafile", "schemas/my_schema.json"]
      types_or: []  # reset to default
      files: ^data/.*\.meta$
```

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: Works as intended. It was an honour to get an answer!